# Code for tap on text view to display text

Tags: android

i am developing an android app,this is my first app development,

As per my requirement , i need code to implement UI as below in the image.

Hopping the image is explaining my requirement. the below image is the App UI view. Thanks..

[image]

I have used the below code , but it is not working. can anyone finds the fault..

```
 - DrinkActivity.java

TextView t ;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);
            t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            t.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
            }
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            t.setText("My text on click");  
            }

 - activity_drink.xml


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:text="This is my first text"
 android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textSize="28sp"
 android:editable="true"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="onClick">

 </TextView>
```

Comment: Your clicking and setting Text on the same Text view. Is that intentional

Answer (score 0):

You could achive this behavior by designing 2 fragments:

**1.** The first one will be a simple TextView fragment that will display your tab text only.

**2.** The second fragment will be as a LinaerLayout vertical layout that will contain 2 TextViews one after another, the first will be the same TextView as in the first fragment while the second TextView will contain the description of your tab.

then all what you should do is on the click of the first fragment replace it with the second one using this code:

```
 if (!isTabOpen)
 {
     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.remove(TabFragment)
     .add(R.id.containerForFragments,TabAndDescriptionFragment)
     .commit();
 }
 else
 {
      fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.remove(TabAndDescriptionFragment)
     .add(R.id.containerForFragments,TabFragment)
     .commit(); 
 }
```

after you have created the plusButtonFragment and the userNewFragment.

Comment: This is way overkill for something so simple.

Comment: A simple TextView with an onClick implementation that changes the visibility of the ScrollView from View.INVISIBLE to View.VISIBLE will suffice

Comment: yeah maybe you right. but what if he want's to recopy this and create a scrollview full of those? I think there will be a problem placing many scrollviews inside of a scrollview and by this way he can be much more flexible.

Comment: I have modified in the question.. i have added the code which i have used..which is not working

Comment: @SamitKumarPatra, I can't because i don't have it. I will have to write it the same way as you would. We are here to guide you and answer any question you might have but not to write the code for you.